# Slim: Comment syntax inside method calls

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have a method call in my slim template that looks like

```
= concept(@table_cell, nil, { \
  date: @date,
  month: @date,
})
```

Now I'd like to add a comment at the end of the `month` line. What delimiter should I use? With either `/` or `#` or I get an error

```
Unknown line indicator
    })
    ^
```

Comment: Looks like you've hit a bug or limitation in Slim. You could file a bug report, or work around it, but there's no real answer here. Neither `/` or `#` will work.

Comment: Looks like I came across a longstanding issue: https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/224

Comment: Is it the trailing comma after the second `@date`?